# What happens when we access from the datanode in Hive?

Tags: hive

In a cluster having Hive installed, if i want to put a file or create a table from the datanode, what happens?

If i do so, will it contact the namenode and do the usual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although metadata and related stuff like authorization of metadata etc are controlled by Hive Metastore, the underlying data is controlled by HDFS only. So, NameNode is very much involved right from the beginning.

You can run hive anywhere, not necessarily on the namenode. You can run it on a DataNode or a utility server other than name node as well.

When you create a table in Hive a directory gets created corresponding to this table and the corresponding metadata gets added to the NameNode metadata file(`fsimage`). The location of this newly created directory is inside the directory controlled by `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir` property which defaults to `/user/hive/warehouse`(could be changed if you want). So if you do something like this :

```
hive> create table t1(f1 int, f2 int) row format delimited fields terminated by ',';
```

It'll create an empty directory in your HDFS, like this :

```
/user/hive/warehouse/t1
```

Now, when you load some data into this table using the `load` command the source file is moved from the the source path into the `/user/hive/warehouse/t1` directory. It is again a filesystem system operation and NameNode will be involved in this as well. If you do something like this :

```
load data inpath '/dir1/in.txt' into table t1;
```

This will move the file `in.txt` from the directory `/dir1` into the directory `/user/hive/warehouse/t1` which involves NameNode.

Don't know if this is exactly what you need.

Comment: Hi, This was very informative. Thank you. So just to be clear. If i run my hive queries from the Data node, the usual process  happens like how it happens when i access from the name node or any client server?

Comment: Hello. Yes. The process remains same.

Comment: +1 Quite informative. I am very new to both hadoop and hive. Does this mean that when I load data into Hive and want it spread across all nodes, I have to do this manually? That is, simply using a statement like LOAD DATA ... will only work where Hive is installed and Place data in the warehouse directory on that node. If I go to a worker node, I have to create this directory myself on that node and Place data there manually?

Comment: @UmaN : No. Once data is inside HDFS, it gets spread across all the nodes automatically.